# Passing string from wpf application to winforms application

Tags: wpf, string, winforms

I have an existing CAD WinForms macro written in C# that manages file oppening (some minor filtering). I have however developed PLM tools in WPF for file storage and project management that allow me to filter records via tags with ordering by accuracy.

I'd like to:
1. open WPF app in my winforms macro
2. recieve a string from said WPF app representing filepath

How would you recomend going about point 2 without use of intermediate files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPC to open a channel that can be used to communicate cross-process. Here's a barebones implementation which should be easy to adapt to your purpose:

---

**Server**

```
void Main()
{
    StringWriter writer = null;
    IChannel serverChannel = null;

    try
    {
        serverChannel = new IpcChannel("localhost:9090");
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(StringWriter), "Writer.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
    }
    catch(RemotingException ex)
    {
        ex.Dump();
    }

    writer = (StringWriter)Activator.GetObject(typeof(StringWriter), "ipc://localhost:9090/Writer.rem");
    var quit = false;

    while(!quit)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                quit = true;
            });
        task.Wait(1000);
        var builder = writer.GetStringBuilder();
        if (builder.Length > 0)
        {
            builder.ToString().Dump();
            break;
        }
    }

    writer.Dispose();
    ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(serverChannel);
    "Server shutdown.".Dump();
}
```

([Download in LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/3p97rp.linq))

---

**Client**

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
        var server = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
        server.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

        Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
        config["name"] = "localhost:9090";
        config["typeFilterLevel"] = "Full";
        config["impersonate"] = "false";
        config["tokenImpersonationLevel"] = "Impersonation";
        config["useDefaultCredentials"] = "True";
        config["secure"] = "True";

        var channel = new IpcChannel(config, client, server);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);

        var remoteType = new WellKnownClientTypeEntry(typeof(StringWriter), "ipc://localhost:9090/Writer.rem");

        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(remoteType);
        string objectUri;
        var messageSink = channel.CreateMessageSink("ipc://localhost:9090/Writer.rem", null, out objectUri);

        Console.WriteLine("The URI of the message sink is {0}.", objectUri);

        if (messageSink != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The type of the message sink is {0}.", messageSink.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
    catch(RemotingException)
    {
    }

    var writer = (StringWriter)Activator.GetObject(typeof(StringWriter), "ipc://localhost:9090/Writer.rem");
    writer.WriteLine("Hello from client!");
}
```

([Download in LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/v8bol3.linq))